# Subclassing Meteor.users() to get different user types

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In meteor, there is the `Meteor.users` collection in the database. I want several different types of users, I want a lot of the same methods that a

```
// after creating a user profile and sending an email to confirm profile
enrollUser: function(id) {
  var profile = MyCollection.findOne(id);
  // send enrollment email
  // when user confirms email and sets a password, they are registered as a user.
  // `profile` is added as the `user.profile`, with the email in `profile` registered
}
```

It seems like you have to create a user in order to send an enrollment email.

Is there any way to create the profile and register the profile to a new user on an enrollment link?

Answer (score 1):

[Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) runs right after you create a new user.

To have multiple types of user, you can use the [meteor roles package](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles).

```
Accounts.onCreateUser( function(options, user) {
    //carry over any profile information resulting from the sign-up method (google, etc)
    if (options.profile) user.profile = options.profile;

    //send your email here

    //add special role
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(user, ['special-user']);
});
```